# How to display a Word document that contains links and bookmarks, to SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, word

I have a word document that contains links. The links take the user to bookmarks in the same document.

I want to display this document in SharePoint 2010, but have the links and bookmarks still working.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

So... this what worked for me. There may be a shorter/better way to do it, but this works.

1. Open a new page in SharePoint. It opens by default with a "Content Editor" web-part, which is what you need anyway.
2. Save your Word document as "Web page, filtered". Let's assume your file was called "MyFile". You now have a file named "MyFile.htm"
3. With a simple text editor (e.g. Notepad), open "MyFile.htm", select all and copy.
4. In SharePoint, open the new page and set it to Edit mode. In the Editing Tools section, Format Text tab, "Markup" section of the ribbon, click on the arrow to the left of the "HTML" icon and select "Edit HTML Source"
5. Select everything in the box that opens up and delete it.
6. Paste the text you copied from MyFile.htm
7. Select OK, then Save & close the page.

Done.

Michael